# Using libmms from Objective-C

Tags: c, objective-c

I want to use libmms in an objective-c project. I've taken the project from here - http://www.tunein-radio.com/lgpl.html - and included the libmms library in my own project. This avoids me having to compile libmms myself. Initially I just want to see if it works and hopefully output some audio.

Here's what I have so far in my header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "mmsio.h"
#import "mms.h"



#define streamURL @"path/to/stream"

@interface radiotestAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
 struct mms_t_io *io;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;


@end
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here but think I need to use this method from mms.h:

```
mms_t* mms_connect (mms_io_t *io, void *data, const char *url, int bandwidth);
```

However, I'm not well versed enough in C to unravel the libmms code. Can anyone offer any advice? I'd be happy to pay for some tuition but want to understand this myself.

What frameworks should I be using to read the *mms_t* response type from the above method?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never used libmms but when looking into the source code the interface seems to be very simple:

1. You connect with `mms_connect` and receive a connection instance.
2. You read from the stream using the opened connection using `mms_read`.
3. You close the connection using `mms_close`.

For advanced functionality you have the other `mms_*` functions.
The IO (mms_io_t) can be `null`. In this case a default implementation will be used for I/O.

BTW I wonder how you would program in Objective-C without being versed enough to understand C code (the libmms code seems straight forward and easy to understand).

**Update:**

I cannot see where the libmms does any video decoding. There are some methods for seeking and getting header/packet information. I don't have any knowledge about video decoding - so I cannot say if you have to decode the stream data prior to playing it or if the iPhone can handle it directly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Coding in Objective-C using existing apple frameworks and the wealth of tutorials / documentation available is a very different proposition to coding using C libraries. Simple for you != simple for everybody. I don't need video decoding - just audio. I think iPhone apps like TuneIn radio use FFMPEG to decode anything which isn't natively handled.

Comment: Nevertheless - when programming Objective-C - you are actually writing C with OO enhancements. Maybe you don't need to dig into pointers (although every object reference like `UIWindow *` is one) nor into structs and unions. However the libmms-library is definitly not complicated or even complex C code.